# $(z-1)^5 = z^5$ for complex $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

So the question asks to find $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(z-1)^5 = z^5$.

I argued that:

$(\frac{z}{z-1})^5 = 1 = e^{2k \pi i}$

so $\frac{z}{z-1} = e^{\theta i}$

where $\theta = \frac{2k \pi}{5}$

so rearranging gives

$z = \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{i \theta} -1} = \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{i \phi}(e^{i \phi} - e^{-i \phi})}$ where $\phi = \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{k \pi}{5}$

$z = \frac{e^{i \phi}}{2i \sin (\phi)} = \frac{ \cos \phi + i \sin \phi}{2i \ sin \phi} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot \phi = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} \cot \frac{k \pi}{5}$ for k = 1, ...4

However the answer says that it should be +cot, not -, but I can't see where I have dropped a negative.

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks

Comment: If you have $y^5 = 1$ (in this case $y = \frac{z}{z-1}$) should you get 5 solutions (run $k$ from 0 through 4)?

Comment: If you expand the bracket the $z^{5}$ terms cancel so you are really solving a quartic for 4 solutions.
Also: If you define $\omega = \frac{z}{z-1}$ then you can't have $z=1$

Comment: How do you get from $z = \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{i \phi}(e^{i \phi} - e^{-i \phi})}$ to $\frac{e^{i \phi}}{2 i \sin(\phi)}$?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has been dropped and everything is  fine.  Since

\begin{align*}
\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)
&=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)}
=\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)}
=-\cot\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)\\
\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)
&=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)}
=\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)}
=-\cot\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)
\end{align*}

> we have
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\{\frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{-}\frac{i}{2}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\Bigg|1\leq k \leq 4\right\}
> =\left\{\frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{+}\frac{i}{2}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\Bigg|1\leq k \leq 4\right\}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Ah so they're subsumed the -ve into the argument, so they're just going the other way around the plane.
Stupid - I should have thought of that. Many thanks Markus!

Comment: @M.L.: You're welcome.